# Clear text box in Jquery Autocomplete after selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to clear the textbox having Jquery Autocomplete once the user has made the selection.

I tried to clear the field by :

```
select: function(event, ui) {
   $(this).val('');
}
```

But this is not working.I am using jquery-1.6.4 and jquery-ui-1.8.16.

Any Ideas?

Comment: i noticed your code says "select". Just want to clarify that it's a textbox and not a select box before I offer a solution.

Comment: @CoreyRS: `select` is the name of the option you pass to `autocomplete` to hook the event when the user selects one of the auto-complete choices.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The [select](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select) event occurs before the field is updated. You will have to cancel the event to avoid the field being updated after you have cleared it:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).val("");
    return false;
}
```

*Update:* As T.J. pointed out below, it's slightly faster to update the `value` DOM property directly instead of going through [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2):

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    this.value = "";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 Or just `this.value = "";`, as in [their examples](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote).

Answer (score 8):

I'm using jQuery UI version 1.8.23 and `$(this).val("");` on `select` event hasn't worked for me, but this did:

```
$("selector").autocomplete({
    // ...
    close: function(el) {
        el.target.value = '';
    }
});
```

Comment: worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select: function(event, ui) {
input.value='';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this:

```
$("#your_autocomplete_sub_listview_id").children().addClass("ui-screen-hidden");
```

which will hide all the autocomplete filtered list upon selecting it.