# Clear textbox after auto complete select in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have implemented the autocomplete using JQuery, when I select the data, it gets stored in the result table, after selecting, I need to clear the autocomplete textbox which i'm not able to. Searched for the same and got this [Clear text box in Jquery Autocomplete after selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607938/clear-text-box-in-jquery-autocomplete-after-selection), but i did not know where to place it and also in the firebug, I got error at function(event,ui).
Pls help... my code is as follows.

```
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {


        $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" ).click(function(o){
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );

    }


    $( "#poolName" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/DataWeb/getPoolName",
                type : 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { name_startsWith: request.term },
                success: function( data ) {
                    console.log(data);
                     response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                             label: item.poolName,
                             value: item.poolName
                        }
                    })); 
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                  ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with this document.getElementById("poolName").value=""; and it is working.

```
function log( message ) {
        document.getElementById("poolName").value="";

        $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" ).click(function(o){
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$( "#poolName" ).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/DataWeb/getPoolName",
            type : 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { name_startsWith: request.term },
            success: function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                         label: item.poolName,
                         value: item.poolName
                    }
                })); 
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (e, i) {
       $('#poolName').val('');   
       return false;    
    }

    ,minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        log( ui.item ?
              ui.item.label :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
    },
    open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }

});

});
```

Comment: can you paste the code you tried or create a jsfiddle(ttp://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can check your code

Comment: I dont get any error, but the textbox will not clear upon selection

Answer (score 2):

try using `return false;` inside select: clause,

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                  ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            return false;
        },
```

Comment: It works fine for me, but why? I have no idea as a javascript newbie.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the other answers is that it didn't had the preventDefault call.

This will work:

```
select: function (e, i) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#poolName').val('');   
   return false;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to do both clear the field and return false

```
select: function(ev, ui) {
  console.log(this, ui.item)
  $(this).val('')
  return false
},
```